# Dispose not being called

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have seen a few posts on here on ways to get an object disposed when it goes out of scope, but nothing I have tried seems to work.

I have a loadingscreen class I created, so I declare the object in a form's xxx_load function.  I want the object to be disposed automatically when it goes out of scope so the hiding of the loading screen will be taken care of automatically.

Here is my loading class

```
public class Loader : IDisposable
{
    public Loader()
    {
        Form.Loadscreen();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Form.UnloadScreen();
    }
}
```

Here is how I am using it in my code.

```
using (Loader loader = new Loader())
{
    //... do some loading processing

    loader.Dispose();
}
```

even though I can verify that loader.Dispose() is being called, there are still times where the object is not being disposed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you see the Dispose() method being called, what makes you think the object is not disposed of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway use just

```
using (Loader loader = new Loader())
{
    //... do some loading processing    

} // loader.Dispose(); will be called automatically. That's IDisposable() for!
```

Comment: It ended up being a threading issue, and once the threading issue was resolved, the "using" method works wonderfully.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you do not need to call `loader.Dispose()` explicitly: that's the whole point behind having a `using` block (it calls `Dispose` automatically).

Second, what do you mean "the object is not being disposed", since `Dispose` is being called (and there's no way it would not be called; the `using` ensures that).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answers that say IDisposable and the using statement take care of disposing your object:

If you are watching taskmanager for the memory footprint, `Dispose()` will not make the amount of allocated memory shrink.  It is a common misconception that your application memory footprint shrinks and expands at the exact moment memory is allocated and deallocated.  This isn't true.  While allocating large chunks of memory may make the footprint increase instantly, deallocation doesn't work that way.

If you are still convinced resources are not being let go, you could try a [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx).

> However, when your application
>   encapsulates unmanaged resources such
>   as windows, files, and network
>   connections, you should use
>   destructors to free those resources.
>   When the object is eligible for
>   destruction, the garbage collector
>   runs the Finalize method of the
>   object.

Comment: A destructor or finalizer is ill-advised and won't make a difference since finalizers aren't guaranteed to be called at all.